# Batch File Check for String in Other File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that writes a line with an ip and a name for the ip in the etc/hosts file. Is there a way to check if this line already exists? Or alternatively just see if a word exists in the file?

edit:
want something like if string exists move on but if not echo

**initial code**

```
findstr "mystring" "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 echo 111.222.333.444 mystring>>%systemroot%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS
```

**Solved: with suggested enhancements**

```
    findstr /V "^#" "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" | findstr /ILC:"mystring" >nul 2>&1 ||^
(echo 111.222.333.444 mystring>>%systemroot%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS)
```

- can ignore commented out lines
- can search for case-insensitive string
- will write a string if string not found

Comment: use `findstr` and conditional execution on success/fail  `&&/||`

Comment: What happens if the line already exists but is preceded by a comment character?

Comment: Im curious to @Compo 's question as well. If there is a way to prevent findstr from searching commented out lines.

Comment: Exclude comment lines first hand `findstr /V "^#" C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /ILC:"mystring" >nul 2>&1 || (echo 111.222.333.444 mystring>>%systemroot%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS)`

Comment: Cant tag you here but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following batch file code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "HostsFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe set "HostsFile=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\drivers\etc\hosts"
if not exist %HostsFile% goto AppendData
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /C:"mystring" %HostsFile% >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /V "$" %HostsFile% >nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo/>>%HostsFile%
:AppendData
>>%HostsFile% echo 111.222.33.44    mystring
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The third line defines the environment variable `HostsFile` with standard file path which is right on batch file being executed on 32-bit Windows by 32-bit `cmd.exe` or on 64-bit Windows by 64-bit `cmd.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

The fourth line takes into account the [Windows File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) according to [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details). The batch file is executed on 64-bit Windows if there is defined an environment variable with name `ProgramFiles(x86)` with a non-empty value. But the batch file is executed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` if there is `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe`. The redirector `Sysnative` does not exist for 64-bit applications. In this case the file `hosts` must be referenced from within 32-bit environment on 64-bit Windows with using the `Sysnative` redirector in file path.

Next is checked if the file `hosts` exists at all. If the file does not exist, the data line to append can be directly written to the file without any further checks whereby the file `hosts` is created in this case.

Otherwise the command **FINDSTR** is used to search case-insensitive with a literally interpreted search string for `mystring` with redirecting the perhaps found line(s) to device **NUL**. **FINDSTR** exits with value `0` if there is at least one positive match and with value `1` if the searched string could not be found on any line.

`if not errorlevel 1` means **IF** exit code is **NOT GREATER OR EQUAL 1**, or in other words **LOWER THAN 1**, or in this case **EQUAL 0** because of **FINDSTR** never exits with a negative value as nearly all applications and commands. So if this condition is true, the file `hosts` contains at least once the searched string and nothing to change on file.

Otherwise **FINDSTR** is used once more to search this time with a regular expression for end of line and to output all lines **not** having a line ending because of option `/V`. So if last line in file `hosts` has no line ending, **FINDSTR** exits with value `0` because of having output one line with no line ending whereby this output is redirected to device **NUL**.

A line ending is appended to file `hosts` if **FINDSTR** exited with value `0` because of file `hosts` ends with no line ending before appending next the data line to add to this file.

The code above does not work if the batch file is not executed with elevated permissions of a local administrator or the file `hosts` has read-only attribute set or is otherwise protected against modification by a script.

BTW: An octet of an IPv4 address cannot be greater than 255. So `111.222.333.444` is a terrible example for an IPv4 address added to file `hosts` because of being an invalid IPv4 address.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)